# Confusion understanding YouTube's loop parameter

Tags: browser, youtube

I have a YouTube video link which I am trying to supply parameters to:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/wU4DgHHwVCc?autoplay=1&start=20&end=25&loop=1
```

Everything else works perfectly except for the `loop` parameter. The video doesn't loop. According to [Google Developer's page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop):

> This parameter has limited support in the AS3 player and in IFrame embeds, which could load either the AS3 or HTML5 player. Currently, the loop parameter only works in the AS3 player when used in conjunction with the playlist parameter.

So even though my Chrome browser is not using AS3, as I've disabled flash, I added the `playlist` parameter to the URL just to see what would happen.

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/wU4DgHHwVCc?autoplay=1&start=20&end=25&loop=1&playlist=wU4DgHHwVCc
```

Now the video does loop but both `start` and `end` parameters are ignored and the video starts at `00:00` instead of `00:20` as specified in the URL.

**Why do I need to specify the `playlist` parameter when I am not using AS3 player?**

**Why does it ignore the `start` and `end` parameters on loop?**

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Chrome version: 60.0.3112.90 (64-bit)

Comment: @pnuts Did you even read the comments on these posts? I was told to post the question here, once I posted it on webapp.se. I couldn't migrate the post due to lack of points.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Youtube documentation... You can modify their shown [**i-frame API**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) example code like below to get a looping effect.

The trick is :

- Set Start Time of video at 20 seconds
- Listen for playback begin **event** and handle with `onPlayerStateChange()` function, which itself starts a `timer` of a **5 seconds** countdown (ie: **5000** millisecs).
- When timer reaches zero it triggers `function handleVideo()` which  itself starts a new `timer` of 5 seconds. Then auto-seeks back to 20 second (start time) in video's timeline. The `timer` now creates a feedback loop.

Try my example code below in a new html page. Can also [**test it here**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick).
Code was tested on Windows/Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() 
      {
        player = new YT.Player('player', 
        {

              width: '100%',
              height: '800',
              videoId: 'wU4DgHHwVCc',
              startSeconds:20,
              //endSeconds:25,
              events: 
              {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
              }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) 
      {
        event.target.seekTo(20);
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(handleVideo, 5000);
          done = true;
        }
      }

      // Custom function to LOOP
      // Moves playhead back to 20 seconds
      function handleVideo() 
      {
        setTimeout(handleVideo, 5000);
        player.seekTo(20);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works fine but the only thing I am allowed to modify is the url, no code.

Comment: _"I can only modify the url, no code"_ then Stackoverflow is wrong place to ask since this site is for **programming** questions not about how to use browser address bar or website URL... Very misleading to ask on **coding** site including tags of languages like `html5` and `AS3` and you even quote Developer's page... yet no code allowed. I wasted my time, thnx.

Comment: See :
 [**Point.5** of the site rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: I've posted the same question on webapps.SE and was told to post here. This is for a project with limited code size. Everything is working perfectly except for this one youtube functionality. Manipulating the url is best way of getting the desired functionality AND and keep to the code size limit. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: Why not just make a page with this code and then share that URL with public instead of using the original Youtube one? You cannot get infinite loop via address bar alone. That's why the API exists, for customized playback via code.

Comment: This project is not meant to be published publicly, its a challenge type thing. If I make a page of this code then I'd have to include it in the overall project code. I'd exceed the code size limit which I am already straddling the threshold.

Comment: @Zindarod that's not making sense. How come you can share `www.youtube.com` with [**all this code**](https://www.youtube.com/embed/wU4DgHHwVCc?autoplay=1&start=20&end=25&loop=1&playlist=wU4DgHHwVCc) (right-click on edges (off video player) & choose _"view source"_) it's okay but if you share `www.mysite.com` with my short Answer code then suddenly it's too much code for your size limit? Anyways in your situation between these Challenge limitations, Youtube server rules, and your inability to use Code for looping, you can forget looping via using only URL in the Address bar.

Comment: I am not using YouTube's code because I am not using their API. I am just using the video URLs. If I make a page of your code or write my own then that code should be included in the overall project. All that aside, the url should work as it was advertised, don't you think? That by itself is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. For single video to loop, you need to have it twice.
Try this out.
    https://www.youtube.com/embed/wU4DgHHwVCc?playlist=wU4DgHHwVCc&autoplay=1&rel=0&loop=1 
Note that "rel" must be set to "0" for any videos that might have them linked as they break the loop.

I made a page for testing [HERE](http://www.myonlinelocation.com/YouTube_Play/youtube_embeded_player/) if you like to test.

Comment: You forgot to add `start` and `end` parameters. I didn't say the video was not looping, I said it ignored the parameters in the loop.